# Detect offline peer in WebRTC connection

Tags: javascript, webrtc

We are developing a video stream from a mobile device to a computer using WebRTC. The mobile device might lose its connection completely and the computer should be able to detect that. Right now, the video just freezes. But neither of the [`EventHandler`s of `RTCPeerConnection`](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#interface-definition) are called in such a situation.

- So how can such a connection failure be detected on the other peer?
- How can a peer detect connection problems on connection establishment in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the iceconnectionstatechange handler should fire after ~5-10 seconds of not receiving data from the peer anymore (in Chrome; Firefox is working on that currently). See https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/states/ for an example.

Comment: Thank you. You were right about Firefox. In Chrome, after about 5 seconds `oniceconnectionstatechange` is called with `currentTarget.iceConnectionState == 'disconnected'` and after 5 more seconds the same handler is called with `currentTarget.iceConnectionState == 'failed'`.

Comment: Echoing comments from @MartinŽdila below, this works in Firefox too now.

Answer (score 10):

As a workaround in Firefox, you could use `getStats` to detect if packets stop coming in:

```
var findStat = (m, type) => [...m.values()].find(s => s.type == type && !s.isRemote);

var hasConnected = new Promise(resolve => pc.oniceconnectionstatechange =
  e => pc.iceConnectionState == "connected" && resolve());

var hasDropped = hasConnected.then(() => new Promise(resolve => {
  var lastPackets = countdown = 0, timeout = 3; // seconds

  var iv = setInterval(() => pc.getStats().then(stats => {
    var packets = findStat(stats, "inbound-rtp").packetsReceived;
    countdown = (packets - lastPackets)? timeout : countdown - 1;
    if (!countdown) resolve(clearInterval(iv)); 
    lastPackets = packets;
  }), 1000);
}));
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4rzhe7n8/

Comment: That's a neat solution, but nearly unreadable if you're not an absolute JS crack :-) But thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @waldgeist, Hello functional programming. :) I wrote it to be a drop-in, and you can't beat the size. Just do `hasDropped.then(() => log("call dropped))` to use it. But I wont lie, I find this more readable than the pages upon pages of JavaScript I often see on SO. JavaScript has more roots in lisp than Java, and es6 gets us closer to its roots.

Comment: You're right, but I still have to get used to it :-)

Comment: Just for curiosity: Is there a special reason why you are re-trying every second and resolve after 3 tries instead of just setting the interval to 3 seconds?

Comment: Answered that last question for myself :-) If you check this every 3 seconds, it can happen that the timeout is effectively up to 3 seconds longer, since it takes at least 2 cycles to detect packet loss.

Comment: I've updated the stats code in this example to match recent spec changes, to work in more browsers.

Comment: In Firefox 55 there is no more need for a workaround. Could be a case also for some older Firefox. Also the code in the answer doesn't work. Use that from the linked jsfiddle demo.

Comment: @MartinŽdila I've updated the code to match the jsfiddle more closely. True, Firefox fires "disconnected" and "failed" now, though using stats still works as well, and can be used to detect problems earlier in all browsers.