# Detecting peer disconnection in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I'd like to react to the situation when a peer is disconnected during a call (e.g. a network issue occurs show an error message). At the moment I end up with a frozen screen of the last frame.

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/iceConnectionState) a "disconnected" should be fired by [`oniceconnectionstatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/oniceconnectionstatechange) if a *"liveness check has failed for at least one component"*.

> "disconnected": liveness check has failed for at least one component. This may be a transient state, e. g. on a flaky network, that can recover by itself.

However turns out Firefox 44 does not have a mechanism for [detecting transport termination](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=852665) and therefore `disconnected` is never fired.

Is there an alternative or "hack" to detect a disconnection I could implement in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35591205/918910.