# How to detect a disconnected WebRTC connection in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, webrtc

According to the documentation on MDN, Firefox supports the "disconnected" and "closed" states for the iceConnectionState property of an RTCPeerConnection:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/iceConnectionState

However, the state won't change if the connection to the peer has been lost. It's "connected" forever and does not fire an oniceconnectionstatechange event, whereas in Chrome the event is fired.

So I am wondering what is the best way to detect in Firefox if a peer has disconnected? I could use the signal or data channels for a keep-alive ping, but that's rather hacky.

Comment: See workaround in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35591205/918910).

Comment: Yes, you're right, this answers this question. Thanks!